# Why the target variable can't find the object name "Base"?

Tags: unity, c#

"Base" is in another scene but I thought Find will find it even if it's in another scene.

```
public class DronesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public float movementSpeed;
    public float launchTime;

    public Transform dronesUnchild;

    private List<GameObject> drones = new List<GameObject>();
    private static System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    private void Awake()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("Base");
    }
```

but target is null when running the game.

this is a screenshot of the hierarhcy the script is attached to the Missile Launcher in the SampleScene and the "Base" is in the Example_01 scene.

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: Do you get any different behaviour if you use Start instead of Awake? Start runs later, which might give enough time for the Example_01 scene to finish loading.

Comment: @DMGregory indeed it's working in the Start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Awake()` gets called immediately as soon as the object has spawned/loaded. It's almost like a constructor, in that it will finish before a call to `Instantiate()` returns the newly spawned object.

That means that anything else that's being spawned in the same/subsequent pass is not necessarily in existence yet.

In this case, it's likely that your first scene loads and calls `Awake()` on all its objects before the second scene has finished loading, so the object simply doesn't exist yet to be found.

By moving your search to `Start()`, you delay it until just before the first `Update()` tick, giving time for the rest of the scene(s) to finish loading so their objects are ready for you to find.